# Select name by id from another column with join another table

Tags: mysql

Huh, this is the simplest title that I could think of.

So this is my problem. I have two table (data for example): 
Table:

```
EMPLOYEES
=====================================================
ID    NAME    SUPERVISOR    LOCATION    SALARY
-----------------------------------------------------
34       John                  AL          100000
17       Mike    34            PN          75000
5        Alan    34            LE          25000
10       Dave    5             NY          20000
```

And second table (data for example):

```
BONUS
========================================
ID        Bonus
----------------------------------------
17        5000
34        5000
10        2000
```

I have to select employee's name, supervisor's name and bonus of everyone who got a bonus greater than 1000. So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT e.name, e.supervisor, b.bonus from employees e join bonus as b on b.empid = e.empid where b.bonus > 1000
```

But I dont know how to replace supervisors ID with name to get this result:

```
RESULT:
=====================================
Name     Supervisor    Bonus
-------------------------------------
Dave     Alan          2000
John     -             5000
Mike     John          5000
```

Can you please help me? I'm really out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join against the `employees` table a second time; you can use aliases to distinguish between the two references to the same table:

```sql
SELECT e.name, s.name AS supervisor, b.bonus
FROM   employees AS e
  JOIN bonus     AS b USING (empid)
  LEFT JOIN employees AS s ON s.empid = e.supervisor
WHERE  b.bonus > 1000
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5328fd/1/0).

A `LEFT JOIN` is required because you also wish to include employees who have no supervisor (e.g. John).  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.

An alternative, less efficient (but sometimes easier to understand), way would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.name, (SELECT name FROM employees WHERE empid=e.supervisor), b.bonus
FROM   employees AS e
  JOIN bonus     AS b USING (empid)
WHERE  b.bonus > 1000
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5328fd/3/0).

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the table to itself:

`SELECT e.NAME as EmployeeName, s.NAME as SupervisorName FROM EMPLOYEES e join EMPLOYEES s ON e.SUPERVISOR = s.ID`

That will give you employees and supervisors.  Go from there to get the employees meeting your criteria.